# configure: error: no boost.filesystem library found

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, boost

So I'm trying to install ncmpcpp though this [github](https://github.com/arybczak/ncmpcpp), and the first step is to run the `sh autogen.sh` script. I've run into a few missing libraries, etc., but I've been able to install them and move on- up until now. I've done some searching and installed a handful of things I thought would help fix it, but to no avail.

`sudo apt-get install libboost1.55-all-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libboost-system-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libboost-system1.54-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libboost1.54-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-thread-dev`

Truth is I don't know enough about Boost or what I'm missing to fix it on my own.

This is where the problem starts:

> checking for boost/filesystem.hpp... yes
>
> checking for main in -lboost_filesystem-mt... no
>
> configure: error: no boost.filesystem library found

edit: Here are the surrounding lines to '-lboost_filesystem-mt' in the config.log file.

> configure:15510: checking for main in -lboost_filesystem-mt
>
> configure:15529: g++ -o conftest -g -O2 -std=c++0x   conftest.cpp -lboost_filesystem-mt   >&5
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mt
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> configure:15529: $? = 1
>
> configure: failed program was:
>
> | /* confdefs.h */

... and then it goes on to describe the confdefs.h file.

Comment: Why are you installing both boost-1.55 and boost-1.54? Anyway, look in config.log for a detailed report. Search for the word "error" or `-lboost_filesystem-mt` in there.

Comment: If it's not a problem for you install all boost files with `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

Comment: @n.m. Because the first didn't work so I tried the other. I'll add the surrounding lines in the org. question.

Comment: @prajmus Did that- didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove these linkes from `configure.ac` (section "setting boost environment"):

```
AS_IF([test -z "${BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX+x}"], [BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=-mt])
AC_ARG_VAR([BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX], [Boost library name suffix [default=-mt]])
```

Long ago, the Boost libraries used to have a `-mt` suffix to indicate that they were multithreading-aware. Debian/Ubuntu dropped this years ago. Maybe other distributions retained it. The Boost library names were never very standardized in any case, which is why `configure` scripts often try do deal with them, often in broken ways.

You can either remove these two lines or call it like this:

```
$ BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX="" ./autogen.sh
```

The proper fix is to convert the script to use the Boost macros from [the Autoconf Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/index.html#Top).

Comment: Thanks! Running into other errors now but this has indeed solved my question. Doumo-arigatou!

Comment: The next error is probably that you need libncursesw5-dev :) Detection of ordinary libncurses seems broken as well.